# virtual env problems while cloning projects from github in different os

Tags: python, django

i've been looking for answers in stackoverflow and over all the web but still don't get it, i started a new project and upload it to a repository in github, all this i did it from a MAC computer, everything fine until here, but... i tried cloning my project in an Windows computer and i can not activate my venv, to activate the venv in MAC there is a bin file, so i type the following commands in the terminal, 'source bin/activate' and it works fine, but i understand that in windows there is a Script folder which i dont have because i created and activated my project for the first time in MAC, there is a way which is deleting the venv directory everytime i clone my project in a different OS but i dont think that's a good pratice, so i would like to know which is the correct way of doing this, which are your recommendations? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virtual environment still has references back to the host machine's python installation. Since Macs and PCs have different locations for where python is located/installed, besides the fact that a virtualenv is much different on a PC than on a Mac (even though they accomplish the same task), a virtualenv created on a Mac will not work out of the box if you transfer the files to a PC.

I recommend adding your virtualenv's folder to your gitignore, then just creating separate environments on your Mac and PC.

Comment: Oh that's a great idea! Thanks, do you think having two folder containing an individual env inside the git repository so when cloning only activate the correct one for the machine will affect my project? the thing is that i use pycharm, so when i start a new project it automatically creates a virtualenv.

Comment: The way a gitignore works is that git completely ignores the folder(s)/file(s) you specify. So, if you add the virtualenv folder to the gitignore file you can modify the virtualenv folder on Mac and it won't affect the ones on other computers when you push your changes. You can also then modify the PC folder to have a PC-compatible virtualenv, and use that for your PC.
There shouldn't be any need for multiple folders with venvs.

Comment: Oh thanks man! That was the answer i was looking for, i appreciate it man, you saved my day!